# Openshift - ssh to a specific gear

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

*if I have more than once gear* I know how to check logs of an specific gear but I don't know how to connect through ssh to a specific gear.

I'm looking for something like:

```
rhc ssh -g gear_id
```

## Why?

Because I'm having issues when I'm trying to execute this

```
f = open(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR']+'/myfile.sh', 'w+')
```

I'm getting an error trying to access that path, and I think it's because is being executed in a different gear.
So I want to check what is the value for `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` in every gear.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see all the gears in an application:

`rhc app show --app <app-name> --gears ssh`

Then, to ssh into a specific gear just grab one of the ssh urls that is shown and:

`ssh <SSH-URL>`